# ADF convert Lookup Activity Output to list

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I retrieve activity('GetData').output.value and the result is :

```
'[{\"name\":\"8.0\"},{\"name\":\"8.1\"},{\"name\":\"7.2\"}]'
```

but I need

```
"8.0","8.1","7.2"
```

Do you have any ideas how to convert?
I've tried with ForEach activity and then use item().name but there is an error without message.

Comment: Do you need to iterate through it or do you need the combined string?  Either way, use a For Each loop.  Specify the items and then use @item().name within the loop.  Use the Append Variable activity inside the loop if you need to assemble the concatenated string.

Comment: Inside a loop I have a copy activity which retrieve data from API (item().name is a part of query). Why append variable?

Comment: Only use Append if you need to construct your string like: "8.0","8.1","7.2".  If you are just iterating then you do not need to do that, it wasn’t clear from your question.

Comment: I've used append variable but I receive : '[\"8.1\",\"8.0\",\"7.2\"].

Comment: It's because API :( variable is created in a right way.

Comment: I've added copy activity to the loop and try to iterate by values but I have an error : The action 'CopyIds' is nested in a foreach scope of multiple levels. Referencing repetition actions from outside the scope is supported only when there are no multiple levels of nesting

Comment: can you clarify what is the type of the output you are trying to construct, is it an array of values, or a single string of combined values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is going to be static then you could just use an:

```
@replace(replace(replace(replace(string(variables('TestArray')), '{"name":', ''), '}', ''), '[', ''), ']', '')
```

**The Pros**: You don't have to use a ForEach, especially if there are hundreds of potential name fields in the output.

**The Cons**: This method is rigid so that it will only work if your output is always in this format.

See screenshots and comments below:
[image: Initial Output]
[image: Final Output]

The Quotes will always be escaped when viewing the string output, ADF automatically escapes all quote characters, but when the variable/output is actually used the escaped characters are ignored. Here is proof of this using the output as an additional column to write the output to a DB column:
**Screenshot 1 (Additional Column in Sink)**
[image: Additional Column value being set]
**Screenshot 2 (The mapping schema)**
[image: DB Mapping]
**Screenshot 3 (Showing the output does not contain escapes in the DB)**
[image: Output from DB]

Comment: Add extra replace and split based on above formula, so that can store as a Array variable

@split(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(string(variables('TestArray')), '{"name":', ''), '}', ''), '[', ''), ']', ''),'"',''),',')

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure if the OP wanted a string or array, but either way will work.